# Does functions in API make system calls themselves or system calls made by API are aided by system-call interface in the runtime support system?

Tags: api, operating-system, system-calls

I was going through the Dinosaur book by Galvin where I faced the difficulty as asked in the question.

> Typically application developers design programs according to an **application programming interface (API)**. The API specifies a set of functions that are available to an application programmer, including the parameters that are passed to each function and the return values the programmer can expect.

The text adds that:

> Behind the scenes the functions that make up an API typically invoke the actual system calls on behalf of the application programmer. For example, the Win32 function `CreateProcess()` (which unsurprisingly is used to create a new process) actually calls the `NTCreateProcess()` system call in the Windows kernel.

From the above two points I came to know that: Programmers using the API, make the function calls to the API corresponding to the system call which they want to make. The concerning function in the API then actually makes the system call.

Next what the text says confuses me a bit:

> The run-time support system (a set of functions built into libraries included with a compiler) for most programming languages provides a **system-call interface** that serves as the link to system calls made available by the operating system. ***The system-call interface intercepts function calls in the API and invokes the necessary system calls within the operating system.*** Typically, a number is associated with each system call, and the system-call interface maintains a table indexed according to these numbers. The system call interface then invokes the intended system call in the operating-system kernel and returns the status of the system call and any return values.

The above excerpt makes me feel that the functions in the API does not make the system calls directly. There are probably function built into the system-call interface of the runtime support system, which are waiting for **an event of system call** from the function in the API.

[image: Diagram]

The above is a diagram in the text explaining the working of the system call interface.

The text later explains the working of a system call in the C standard library as follows:

[image: C Standard Library]

which is quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't totally understand the terminology of the excerpts you shared. Some terminology is also wrong like in the blue image at the bottom. It says the standard C library provides system call interfaces while it doesn't. The standard C library is just a standard. It is a convention. It just says that, if you write a certain code, then the effect of that code when it is ran should be according to the convention. It also says that the C library intercepts printf() calls while it doesn't. This is general terminology which is confusing at best.

The C library doesn't intercept calls. As an example, on Linux, the open source implementation of the C standard library is glibc. You can browse it's source code here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/latest/source. When you write C/C++ code, you use standard functions which are specified in the C/C++ convention.

When you write code, this code will be compiled to assembly and then to machine code. Assembly is also a higher level representation of machine code. It is just closer to the actual code as it is easier to translate to it then C/C++. The easiest case to understand is when you compile code statically. When you compile code statically, all code is included in your executable. For example, if you write

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

the printf() function is called in stdio.h which is a header provided by gcc written specifically for one OS or a set of UNIX-like OSes. This header provides prototypes which are defined in other .c files provided by **glibc**. These .c files provide the actual implementation of printf(). The printf() function will make a system call which rely on the presence of an OS like Linux to run. When you compile statically, the code is all included up to the system call. You can see my answer here: [Who sets the RIP register when you call the clone syscall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66853510/who-sets-the-rip-register-when-you-call-the-clone-syscall/66863181#66863181). It specifically explains how system calls are made.

In the end you'll have something like assembly code pushing some arguments into some conventionnal registers then the actual `syscall` instruction which jumps to an MSR. I don't totally understand the mechanism behind printf() but it will jump to the Linux kernel's implementation of the `write` system call which will write to the console and return.

I think what confuses you is that the "runtime-support system" is probably referring to higher level languages which are not compiled to machine code directly like Python or Java. Java has a virtual machine which translates the bytecode produced by compilation to machine code during runtime using a virtual machine. It can be confusing to not make this distinction when talking about different languages. Maybe your book is lacking examples.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually just as you have pointed out the discrepancies between the text and the real concept, that is exactly where I was having the problem as. And yes the book lacks examples probably as you say.