# Operating Systems: Processes, Pagination and Memory Allocation doubts

Tags: memory, process, operating-system, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have several doubts about processes and memory management. List the main. I'm slowly trying to solve them by myself but I would still like some help from you experts =).

I understood that the data structures associated with a process are more or less these:
text, data, stack, kernel stack, heap, PCB.

If the process is created but the LTS decides to send it to secondary memory, are all the data structures copied for example on SSD or maybe just text and data (and PCB in kernel space)?

Pagination allows you to allocate processes in a non-contiguous way:

1. How does the kernel know if the process is trying to access an illegal memory area? After not finding the index on the page table, does the kernel realize that it is not even in virtual memory (secondary memory)? If so, is an interrupt (or exception) thrown? Is it handled immediately or later (maybe there was a process switch)?
2. If the processes are allocated non-contiguously, how does the kernel realize that there has been a stack overflow since the stack typically grows down and the heap up? Perhaps the kernel uses virtual addresses in PCBs as memory pointers that are contiguous for each process so at each function call it checks if the VIRTUAL pointer to the top of the stack has touched the heap?
3. How do programs generate their internal addresses? For example, in the case of virtual memory, everyone assumes starting from the address 0x0000 ... up to the address 0xffffff ... and is it then up to the kernel to proceed with the mapping?
4. How did the processes end? Is the system call exit called both in case of normal termination (finished last instruction) and in case of killing (by the parent process, kernel, etc.)? Does the process itself enter kernel mode and free up its associated memory?
5. Kernel schedulers (LTS, MTS, STS) when are they invoked? From what I understand there are three types of kernels:

- separate kernel, below all processes.
- the kernel runs inside the processes (they only change modes) but there are "process switching functions".
- the kernel itself is based on processes but still everything is based on process switching functions.

6. I guess the number of pages allocated the text and data depend on the "length" of the code and the "global" data. On the other hand, is the number of pages allocated per heap and stack variable for each process? For example I remember that the JVM allows you to change the size of the stack.
7. When a running process wants to write n bytes in memory, does the kernel try to fill a page already dedicated to it and a new one is created for the remaining bytes (so the page table is lengthened)?

I really thank those who will help me.
Have a good day!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have **lots** of misconceptions. Let's try to clear some of these.

> If the process is created but the LTS decides to send it to secondary memory, are all the data structures copied for example on SSD or maybe just text and data (and PCB in kernel space)?

I don't know what you mean by LTS. The kernel can decide to send some pages to secondary memory but only on a page granularity. Meaning that it won't send a whole text segment nor a complete data segment but only a page or some pages to the hard-disk. Yes, the PCB is stored in kernel space and never swapped out (see here: [Do Kernel pages get swapped out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535379/do-kernel-pages-get-swapped-out)).

> How does the kernel know if the process is trying to access an illegal memory area? After not finding the index on the page table, does the kernel realize that it is not even in virtual memory (secondary memory)? If so, is an interrupt (or exception) thrown? Is it handled immediately or later (maybe there was a process switch)?

On x86-64, each page table entry has 12 bits reserved for flags. The first (right-most bit) is the `present` bit. On access to the page referenced by this entry, it tells the processor if it should raise a page-fault. If the present bit is 0, the processor raises a page-fault and calls an handler defined by the OS in the IDT (interrupt 14). Virtual memory is not secondary memory. It is not the same. Virtual memory doesn't have a physical medium to back it. It is a concept that is, yes implemented in hardware, but with logic not with a physical medium. The kernel holds a memory map of the process in the PCB. On page fault, if the access was not within this memory map, it will kill the process.

> If the processes are allocated non-contiguously, how does the kernel realize that there has been a stack overflow since the stack typically grows down and the heap up? Perhaps the kernel uses virtual addresses in PCBs as memory pointers that are contiguous for each process so at each function call it checks if the VIRTUAL pointer to the top of the stack has touched the heap?

The processes are allocated contiguously in the virtual memory but not in physical memory. See my answer here for more info: [Each program allocates a fixed stack size? Who defines the amount of stack memory for each application running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69623703/each-program-allocates-a-fixed-stack-size-who-defines-the-amount-of-stack-memor/69633252#69633252). I think stack overflow is checked with a page guard. The stack has a maximum size (8MB) and one page marked not present is left underneath to make sure that, if this page is accessed, the kernel is notified via a page-fault that it should kill the process. In itself, there can be no stack overflow attack in user mode because the paging mechanism already isolates different processes via the page tables. The heap has a portion of virtual memory reserved and it is very big. The heap can thus grow according to how much physical space you actually have to back it. That is the size of the swap file + RAM.

> How do programs generate their internal addresses? For example, in the case of virtual memory, everyone assumes starting from the address 0x0000 ... up to the address 0xffffff ... and is it then up to the kernel to proceed with the mapping?

The programs assume an address (often 0x400000) for the base of the executable. Today, you also have ASLR where all symbols are kept in the executable and determined at load time of the executable. In practice, this is not done much (but is supported).

> How did the processes end? Is the system call exit called both in case of normal termination (finished last instruction) and in case of killing (by the parent process, kernel, etc.)? Does the process itself enter kernel mode and free up its associated memory?

The kernel has a memory map for each process. When the process dies via abnormal termination, the memory map is crossed and cleared off of that process's use.

> Kernel schedulers (LTS, MTS, STS) when are they invoked?

All your assumptions are wrong. The scheduler cannot be called otherwise than with a timer interrupt. The kernel isn't a process. There can be kernel threads but they are mostly created via interrupts. The kernel starts a timer at boot and, when there is a timer interrupt, the kernel calls the scheduler.

> I guess the number of pages allocated the text and data depend on the "length" of the code and the "global" data. On the other hand, is the number of pages allocated per heap and stack variable for each process? For example I remember that the JVM allows you to change the size of the stack.

The heap and stack have portions of virtual memory reserved for them. The text/data segment start at 0x400000 and end wherever they need. The space reserved for them is really big in virtual memory. They are thus limited by the amount of physical memory available to back them. The JVM is another thing. The stack in JVM is not the real stack. The stack in JVM is probably heap because JVM allocates heap for all the program's needs.

> When a running process wants to write n bytes in memory, does the kernel try to fill a page already dedicated to it and a new one is created for the remaining bytes (so the page table is lengthened)?

The kernel doesn't do that. On Linux, the libstdc++/libc C++/C implementation does that instead. When you allocate memory dynamically, the C++/C implementation keeps track of the allocated space so that it won't request a new page for a small allocation.

**EDIT**

> Do compiled (and interpreted?) Programs only work with virtual addresses?

Yes they do. Everything is a virtual address once paging is enabled. Enabling paging is done via a control register set at boot by the kernel. The MMU of the processor will automatically read the page tables (among which some are cached) and will translate these virtual addresses to physical ones.

> So do pointers inside PCBs also use virtual addresses?

Yes. For example, the PCB on Linux is the task_struct. It holds a field called pgd which is an unsigned long*. It will hold a virtual address and, when dereferenced, it will return the first entry of the PML4 on x86-64.

> And since the virtual memory of each process is contiguous, the kernel can immediately recognize stack overflows.

The kernel doesn't recognize stack overflows. It will simply not allocate more pages to the stack then the maximum size of the stack which is a simple global variable in the Linux kernel. The stack is used with push pops. It cannot push more than 8 bytes so it is simply a matter of reserving a page guard for it to create page-faults on access.

> however the scheduler is invoked from what I understand (at least in modern systems) with timer mechanisms (like round robin). It's correct?

Round-robin is not a timer mechanism. The timer is interacted with using memory mapped registers. These registers are detected using the ACPI tables at boot (see my answer here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/141870/when-are-a-controllers-registers-loaded-and-ready-to-inform-an-i-o-operation/141918#141918). It works similarly to the answer I provided for USB (on the link I provided here). Round-robin is a scheduler priority scheme often called naive because it simply gives every process a time slice and executes them in order which is not currently used in the Linux kernel (I think).

> I did not understand the last point. How is the allocation of new memory managed.

The allocation of new memory is done with a system call. See my answer here for more info: [Who sets the RIP register when you call the clone syscall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66853510/who-sets-the-rip-register-when-you-call-the-clone-syscall/66863181#66863181).

The user mode process jumps into a handler for the system call by calling `syscall` in assembly. It jumps to an address specified at boot by the kernel in the LSTAR64 register. Then the kernel jumps to a function from assembly. This function will do the stuff the user mode process requires and return to the user mode process. This is often not done by the programmer but by the C++/C implementation (often called the standard library) that is a user mode library that is linked against dynamically.

The C++/C standard library will keep track of the memory it allocated by, itself, allocating some memory and by keeping records. Then, if you ask for a small allocation, it will use the pages it already allocated instead of requesting new ones using mmap (on Linux).

Comment: OK thank you. I still have some doubts:
Do compiled (and interpreted?) Programs only work with virtual addresses? So do pointers inside PCBs also use virtual addresses? And since the virtual memory of each process is contiguous, the kernel can immediately recognize stack overflows. By LTS I mean Long Term Scheduler, however the scheduler is invoked from what I understand (at least in modern systems) with timer mechanisms (like round robin).  It's correct? I did not understand the last point. How is the allocation of new memory managed.
Thanks for your time, you are helping me a lot !!

Comment: @Bart Doe I edited my answer for your comment. Feel free to upvote this answer or any post that I link if you think they've been helpful.

Comment: Or to mark it as accepted (since you don't have the reputation to upvote).

Comment: 'The scheduler cannot be called otherwise than with a timer interrupt.' so wrong that words fail me....  You do not understand how operating systems manage the resource of CPU execution:(

Comment: Note that your other stuff here is good, but the scheduler can be entered upon I/O completion, (absolutely vital for good I/O performance), and upon inter-thread signaling.  The timer interrupt is not even strictly necessary for a preemptive scheduler, but it is very useful for timing out sycalls, sleeps and, IF the system CPU resources are overloaded, sharing out CPU between ready threads.

Comment: Yes the scheduler can be called for IO and other stuff definitely.

Comment: It is called though on interrupt. The kernel isn't "running" like a process.

Comment: The CPU is always overloaded by the amount of threads or almost on modern systems seeing the amount of tasks on my ubuntu system at least. There is more threads than core so the scheduler must use the timer.

Comment: The timer interrupt is always necessary even with a preemptive scheduler.

Comment: The scheduler should otherwise be called from user mode which is ridiculous.

Comment: You are right in the end because the threads are created by user interaction. The kernel can thus assume nothing was created if there wasn't a keyboard interrupt. The scheduler will thus be called on mouse/keyboard interaction if a new thread was created by this interaction (like in exec). I simply assume in my answer there is more threads than cores. Maybe the timer is programmed even though threads < cores. That is still to verify.

Comment: just one last question. The TLB must be emptied at each context switch: otherwise the processes could access incorrect physical pages. To reduce the overhead, each entry of the TLB could be labeled with the process PID. But what about page tables instead? Are they always emptied? Because?

Comment: ' The timer interrupt is always necessary even with a preemptive scheduler' no.  It's quite possible to design a system that is driven by I/O completions alone.  It would not be practical for a general-purpose OS, but it could be done.  You would lose the ability to sleep, be unable to time out system calls and unable to share out CPU if overloaded.  So, not good in general, but not inconceivable.

Comment: 'The CPU is always overloaded by the amount of threads or almost on modern systems' well, not this one.  There are currently 1107 threads existing, but only 5/6% CPU use on my 4/8 core i7.  Obviously, my box is not overloaded for CPU execution as there is plenty CPU spare as most threads are not ready/running.